# firewalld and iptables | fail2ban

Tags: iptables, fail2ban, firewalld

I have fail2ban 1.0.2 running on an Almalinux server. Seems to be working as hoped, but I'm puzzled by something.

1. have sshd.local and 00-firewalld.local in jail.d (installed fail2ban and fail2ban-firewalld from epel).
2. 00-firewalld.local contains:

   ```
   [DEFAULT]
   banaction = firewallcmd-rich-rules
   banaction_allports = firewallcmd-rich-rules
   ```

But, when I run fail2ban-client get sshd actions

```
 The jail sshd has the following actions:
 iptables-multiport
```

I was under the impression that it should have returned:

```
 firewallcmd-rich-rules
```

But, nada. Which would probably explain why

```
 firewall-cmd --list-rich-rules
```

returns nothing, whereas

```
 iptables -S
```

returns a list of all of the ip addresses that

```
 fail2ban-client get sshd banip
```

lists. In other words, fail2ban is popping things into iptables, but firewalld seems to be out of the loop.

So, hoping someone can explain what is going on? I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: I think the problem might be I need to put banaction = firewallcmd-rich-rules
banaction_allports = firewallcmd-rich-rules into jail.local, and turn off the default which uses iptables. Sound about right?

Comment: Sounded right - but, nope.  Even after restarting both fail2ban and firewalld, fail2ban-client get sshd returns iptables-multiport, as noted in the OP. So, remain baffled.